# sum of S4 objects in R

Tags: r, operator-overloading, r-s4

I have a S4 class and I would like to define the linear combination of these objects.

Is it possible to dispatch `*` and `+` functions on this specific class?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

here is an example:

```
setClass("yyy", representation(v="numeric"))

setMethod("+", signature(e1 = "yyy", e2 = "yyy"), function (e1, e2) e1@v + e2@v)
setMethod("+", signature(e1 = "yyy", e2 = "numeric"), function (e1, e2) e1@v + e2)
```

then,

```
> y1 <- new("yyy", v = 1)
> y2 <- new("yyy", v = 2)
> 
> y1 + y2
[1] 3
> y1 + 3
[1] 4
```

Answer (score 16):

The `+` operator is part of the Arith group generic (see `?GroupGenericFunctions`) so one can implement all functions in the group with

```
setMethod("Arith", "yyy", function(e1, e2) {
    v = callGeneric(e1@v, e2@v)
    new("yyy", v = v)
})
```

and then with

```
setClass("yyy", representation(v="numeric"))
setMethod(show, "yyy", function(object) {
    cat("class:", class(object), "\n")
    cat("v:", object@v, "\n")
})
setMethod("Arith", "yyy", function(e1, e2) {
    v = callGeneric(e1@v, e2@v)
    new("yyy", v = v)
})
```

One would have

```
> y1 = new("yyy", v=1)
> y2 = new("yyy", v=2)
> y1 + y2
class: yyy 
v: 3 
> y1 / y2
class: yyy 
v: 0.5 
## ...and so on
```

Comment: Is that's assuming that you want to apply the + operator to all slots of the object?

Comment: It is re-dispatching to the arithmetic operator for the slot 'v' of objects e1 and e2. If there were slots v and w, you might write for the body of the method `new("yyy", v = callGeneric(e1@v, e2@v), w = callGeneric(e1@w, e2@w))`