# R: How to overload the `-` operator if you want use `-` in your 'overload' code?

Tags: r, recursion, overloading

Just for fun I am trying to overload the `-` in R so that running

```
some.string - n
```

will give me the *some.string* with the last *n* characters removed.

This is my code in R

```
`-` <- function(x,y) {
  minus <- force(`-`)
  if(typeof(x) == "character" & y >0) {
    return(substr(x,1,minus(nchar(x), as.integer(y))))
  } else {
    return(minus(x,y))
  }
}

"abc" - 2
```

However this seems to cause a an infinitely nested recursion. This is because every time minus is run it tries to run itself. But that's exactly what I am trying to prevent by assigning minus = `-` in the first place?

How do I avoid this endless recursion?

Comment: Admittedly not what you were after, but you can achieve the same by replacing your two `minus(a, b)` with something like `sum(c(a, sign(log(0)) * b))`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `.Primitive("-")` to avoid an endless loop. This should work:

```
`-` <- function(x,y) {
  if(typeof(x) == "character" & y >0) {
    return(substr(x, 1, nchar(x) - as.integer(y)))
  } else {
    .Primitive("-")(x, y)
  }
}
```

Closer to your original idea is to define `minus <- get("-", envir=baseenv())`:

```
`-` <- function(x,y) {
  minus <- get("-", envir=baseenv())
  if(typeof(x) == "character" & y >0) {
    return(substr(x,1,minus(nchar(x), as.integer(y))))
  } else {
    return(minus(x,y))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is another solution using S4 method dispatch. The dispatch will be more elegant compared to using if-else structures and you do not have to mask the primitive function `-`. However for primitive functions it appears that it is not allowed to define methods for atomic data types. Hence, I needed to define a new class "lastCharacters". Actually this makes the last line a bit more readible as the intention of the code is clear...

```
lastCharacters <- setClass("lastCharacters", contains = "numeric")

setMethod("-", 
          signature(e1 = "character", e2 = "lastCharacters"),
          function(e1, e2) {
            substr(e1, 1, nchar(e1) - as.integer(e2))
          })

"abc" - lastCharacters(2)
```

Answer (score 3):

Along the lines of suggestion from @PatrickRoocks, make your own (S3 or [S4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937719/sum-of-s4-objects-in-r/8940777#8940777)) class and dispatch (rather than mask) on that.

```
`-.my` = function(e1, e2) substr(e1, 1, nchar(e1) - e2)

x = c('all', 'the', 'world')
class(x) = 'my'
x - 1
## [1] "al"   "th"   "worl"
## attr(,"class")
## [1] "my"
```

See also ?Ops in the base (for S3) or methods (S4) package, which defines a 'group generic'

```
 Ops.my = function(e1, e2) {
     FUN = get(.Generic, envir = parent.frame(), mode = "function")
     substr(e1, 1, FUN(nchar(e1), e2))
}
```

to implement (in a nonsensical way, for the specific function above -- `substr(x, 1, nchar(x) + 2)` doesn't make sense), `x - 1`, `x + 1`, `x / 2`, etc. in a single definition.

The S4 version (sort of like @Sebastian, and from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937719/sum-of-s4-objects-in-r/8940777#8940777)) is

```
.My = setClass("My", contains="character")
setMethod("Arith", c("My", "numeric"), function(e1, e2) {
    substr(e1, 1, callGeneric(nchar(e1), e2))
})
```

with

```
> .My(c("all", "the", "world")) - 1
An object of class "My"
[1] "al"   "th"   "worl"
```

Answer (score 2):

shadows answer is totally correct and you asked "just for fun", so this is okay. But for any serious program I would highly discourage from such approaches. Overloading `-` in that way will slow down every minus operation in your program and such kind of hacks can cause many other problematic issues.

The neat way to do such overloads is to introduce your own wrapper class, where it is save to overload the operators. For example:

```
specialstring <- 
  setRefClass("specialstring",
               fields = list(str = "character"),
               methods = list(
               initialize = function(str = character(0)) {
                 .self$str <- str
               },
               show = function() { print(.self$str) }
               )
  )

`-.specialstring` <- function(x, y) {
  if (class(x) == "specialstring" && is.numeric(y))
    return(substr(x$str, 1, nchar(x$str) - as.integer(y)))
  else
    stop("Incompatible types for -.specialstring")
}
```

Now specialstring is a string wrapper class which has the desired functionality:

```
x <- specialstring("abc")
x - 1
```

runs fine, whereas `x-x` leads to the intended error message.

If you combine such an operator overloading (which is one the ideas of OOP in R, packages like `igraph` really make use of this ideas!) with the function from shadow, then `x-x` does not lead to the intended error message above (`Incompatible types for -.specialstring`), but leads to the misleading message `Error in y > 0 : comparison (6) is possible...`. Of course, this could be fixed again by even more checks in the `-` overloading, but all these checks are kind of "bad design", where a neat OOP solution is the way one should do.