# How one can delete % from the name of an infix function?

Tags: r, function, infix-notation

Is it possible to define  (+)  function by R, s.t. able to work between its two arguments?

In other words, I'd like to delete `%` from the following infix function (but I can not and I don't know how this problem can be solved):

```
`%(+)%` <- function(x,y)  { x+(2*y) }
2 %(+)% 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User-defined infix operators *must* be surrounded by percent signs in R. So the answer to your question is, "you can't".  Sorry.

From the [R language definition](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Special-operators):

> R allows user-defined infix operators. These have the form of a string of characters delimited by the ‘%’ character. The string can contain any printable character except ‘%’. The escape sequences for strings do not apply here.

The only alternatives I can think of, both rather desperate:

- if `x` and `y` are defined as members of an S4 class then you can [overload dispatch for the + symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937719/sum-of-s4-objects-in-r)
- you could hack the R parser (not recommended!), as in [this example](https://github.com/lionel-/r-source), where someone forked a read-only Github mirror of R to modify the parser (described [here](http://lionel-.github.io/2016/02/15/ideas-for-an-updated-r-syntax/)).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Ben Bolker that you cannot define (+) without the %. However, if you are looking to create a function as per above why not use the following:

```
`&`<- function(x, y) { x+(2*y) }
2&3
#Use rm to remove the defined function
rm(`&`)
```

Comment: Actually you cannot define + as per the requirement because it would lead to an infinite recursion error since you are defining something that he is using in the actual function.